# How to compile latest sources using older gcc glibc versions and run them?

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc

I'm able to compile & run the latest "stockfish chess engine" sources using GCC 4.8 or later on Redhat EL 7.X. The latest source code (alongwith README) is available at https://github.com/mcostalba/Stockfish/tree/master

The commands to compile & build are: (goto "src" directory)

```
gmake build ARCH=x86-64
gmake install
```

However my requirement is to compile & run the same on Redhat EL 6.7 Server where the latest GCC version available is 4.4.7 (& glibc 2.12) as I can NOT upgrade GCC version without actually migrating to RHEL 7.X

Is it possible to modify the latest source to get it compliled & run on old version of gcc/glibc? if yes, would anyone be able to modify the sources (perhaps just Makefile?) for me please?

I tried changing "C ++ 11" to "C ++ 0x" in the "Makefile" but no luck. Please see the error I'm getting when I try to compile latest SF source with GCC 4.4.7:

```
[root@test-server src]#  ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.12
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
[root@test-server src]#  gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[root@test-server src]#  cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)
[root@test-server src]#  uname -r
2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
[root@test-server src]#  gmake build ARCH=x86-64
gmake ARCH=x86-64 COMP=gcc config-sanity
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/root/Stockfish-master/src'

Config:
debug: 'no'
optimize: 'yes'
arch: 'x86_64'
bits: '64'
prefetch: 'yes'
popcnt: 'no'
sse: 'yes'
pext: 'no'

Flags:
CXX: g++
CXXFLAGS: -Wall -Wcast-qual -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -std=c++11  -pedantic -Wextra -Wshadow -m64 -DNDEBUG -O3 -DIS_64BIT -msse -flto
LDFLAGS:  -Wl,--no-as-needed -lpthread -Wall -Wcast-qual -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -std=c++11  -pedantic -Wextra -Wshadow -m64 -DNDEBUG -O3 -DIS_64BIT -msse -flto

Testing config sanity. If this fails, try 'make help' ...

gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Stockfish-master/src'
gmake ARCH=x86-64 COMP=gcc all
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/root/Stockfish-master/src'
g++ -Wall -Wcast-qual -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -std=c++11  -pedantic -Wextra -Wshadow -m64 -DNDEBUG -O3 -DIS_64BIT -msse -flto   -c -o benchmark.o benchmark.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-flto"
gmake[1]: * [benchmark.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Stockfish-master/src'
gmake: * [build] Error 2
[root@test-server src]#
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to modify the latest source to get it compliled & run
>   on old version of gcc/glibc? if yes, would anyone be able to modify
>   the sources (perhaps just Makefile?) for me please?

Sure it's possible. It will take time and effort though.

> I can NOT upgrade GCC version without actually migrating to RHEL 7.X

You can't install the GCC binary from RHEL you mean. But if you have one compiler you can have another.

You have a few options which allow you to manually compile your own GCC and install it to `/opt` or `/usr/local` without messing your system.

You can do it manually or use a tool chain like installing [gentoo`s portage](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Portage) or bootstrapping [pkgsrc](https://www.pkgsrc.org/) which offers [gcc-4.8](http://pkgsrc.se/lang/gcc48)

Although, I am an avid gentoo user, I recommend using pkgsrc on foreign architectures. It's very easy to get started with, and have a vast number of packages.